# Conditional formatting based on value in first row of a datatable in R

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
id = LETTERS[1:10],
score1 = c(30, 45, 30, 28, 33, 29, 27, 27, 31, 30),
score2 = c(40, 27, 30, 28, 47, 29, 27, 51, 31, 30))

df
   id score1 score2
1   A     28     28
2   B     27     27
3   C     30     30
4   D     28     28
5   E     29     29
6   F     29     29
7   G     27     27
8   H     27     27
9   I     31     31
10  J     30     30
```

Is there a way to use conditional formatting to change the colour of the output based on a comparison with the value in the first row?
Specifically, I would like all of the values in the score1 and score2 columns to be red if the score is higher than the value in the first row and green if the score is lower than the value in the first row.

So for score1, values are compared to 30:
These values should be red: 45, 33, 31.
These values should be green: 28, 29, 27, 27

For score 2, values are compared to 40:
These values should be red: 47, 51.
These values should be green: 27, 30, 28, 29, 27, 31, 30.

Comment: Generally speaking, the R console is not a great place for data presentation, and this seems like more effort than it's worth. But with some effort, the Crayon package would probably get you there: https://github.com/r-lib/crayon

Comment: I'm learning something every day.

Comment: I wasn't aware of crayon but had seen formattable: https://renkun-ken.github.io/formattable/ and thought it might be possible with that library.
In either case, I'm still not sure how to setup the conditional.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this post while trying to learn how to do conditional formatting with crayon and string detection.  Found a solution to color your score values green & red as asked. However, I had to turn the crayon stylized numbers into strings to keep the formatting, so I saved them as new variables.  Running cat() on the new variables shows the green & red colors, but it does not show if/when you want to display the entire dataframe.

```
library(crayon)

df$score1_color <- print(ifelse(df$score1 > 30, red(df$score1), green(df$score1)))
df$score2_color <- print(ifelse(df$score2 > 40, red(df$score2), green(df$score2)))

cat(df$score1_color)
cat(df$score2_color)
```